# How to pair Bluetooth mouse with Apple Watch?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, apple-watch

Can I pair my Bluetooth mouse with Apple Watch? Or, can I get the functionality of a mouse with my Apple Watch?

Answer (score 1):

watchOS wasn't designed to be used with a mouse. As such, it does not include mouse drivers or a mouse cursor, and therefore will not pair with a Bluetooth mouse.